# Which directory do I put python modules in?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python.

I'm trying to install beautifulsoup. So far, I've installed pip.

From the beautifulsoup website it says:

> To begin with, make sure that you have the necessary modules
>   installed.
>
> In the example below, we are using Beautiful Soup 4 and Requests on a
>   system with Python 2.7 installed.

Okay, that's great - where is it asking me to place the modules? Do I put the downloaded items into python27/Scripts?

Okay, next:

> Installing BeautifulSoup and Requests can be done with pip:

Here are the commands:

```
$ pip install requests
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

I'm assuming my code would looks something like this from the python intepereter:

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip install requests
>>> pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Where does it know to get 'requests' or 'beautifulsoup4'? That is my main question, I guess.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, `pip install` is to be used from command line.
then, [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/12476379#12476379) might help. Just install pip from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip.
Then, add the path to your pip executable to your Path env. var.
Then, just `pip install requests` and `pip install beautifulsoup4` and it will work.
pip just connects to its servers and fetches the package that was registered to the name you requested.